# Will summer return to the North?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Now that the

> Night King has been defeated

will the normal seasons return to the North i.e. summer, spring and autumn? I haven't read the books and don't think it's mentioned in the TV show. Not looking for opinions only canon facts please.

Comment: If I understand the books correctly, winter brings the White Walkers, not the other way around. But at this point I think it still remains to be seen if the White Walkers cause the log winter or not in the TV show.

Comment: So if winter brings the White Walkers then in 8-9 months the Night's King will be back???

Comment: What I mean is that the White Walkers stay in the frozen north until winter comes and then they march south. Their southern march doesn't cause winter to come. And the winter doesn't create new White Walkers. It's like a migration. That's what I believe is the concept in the books - I might have it wrong. Also the turn of the seasons in Westeros is not on the same cycle as Earth. Meaning it's not 8 - 9 months between each winter. It's years.

Comment: This is undoubtedly going to be answered in the remaining episodes so voted to close per the future works policy.

Comment: I thought the North experienced seasons just like the rest of the realm, only difference is average colder temperatures than the South (I'm sure the North is referenced as having "summer snows")?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I disagree. I doubt there in is enough time left in the show to see a regular changing of the seasons. The only way we would is with an epilogue of some sorts.

Comment: @Skooba if summer returns because of the death of the Night King winter will end in the next episodes. If winter doesn’t end then we can assume that the answer to this question is no.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Surely the seasons of the planet are older than the Night King... There hasn't been anything to suggest that this winter, outside of the army of the dead advancing, is unusual (i.e. more snow, more darkness) in some way. I don't think there will be an endless summer now....

Comment: @Skooba I don't remember in the TV show, but in the books the maesters claim it will be the longest and coldest winter in recent memory. Longest as in years, not mere months. GRRM has also stated seasonal changes in Westeros are influenced by magic, the details of which will be revealed at the end. (Nevermind: I see by your answer that you understand this :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Immediately, probably not; Eventually, absolutely.

It just depends on whether or not it was the Night King's magic that was the cause of the irregular seasons to begin with.

**There were possibly regular seasons in ancient history, even further back than the Age of Heroes**.

Writing and records were rare even back then and most of what we know from that time is legends passed on by story. The Maesters have looked into the matter but have not been able to conclude anything as there is just not enough information from that long ago...

> Though the Citadel has long sought to learn the manner by which it may predict the length and change of seasons, all efforts have been confounded. Septon Barth appeared to argue, in a fragmentary treatise, that **the inconstancy of the seasons was a matter of magical art** rather than trustworthy knowledge. Maester Nicol's The Measure of the Days—otherwise a laudable work containing much of use—seems influenced by this argument. Based upon his work on the movement of stars in the firmament, **Nicol argues unconvincingly that the seasons might once have been of a regular length**, determined solely by the way in which the globe faces the sun in its heavenly course. The notion behind it seems true enough—that the lengthening and shortening of days, if more regular, would have led to more regular seasons—but he could find **no evidence that such was ever the case, beyond the most ancient of tales.**
>
> <sub>*The World of Ice and Fire - Ancient History: The Long Night*</sub>

Comment: thanks for your answer, any chance you feel like voting to re-open this question as some don't seem to think I'm not looking for a n opinion based answer! Thanks

Comment: @Seamusthedog primarily opinion based is the close reason used for the future works policy.

Comment: @Seamusthedog in addition to what TLC said, note that "future work policy" is most of the time temporary. So a question that is closed today, will probably get reopened in... whenever season 8 ends.

Comment: @Jenayah ok, thanks